Convergence of the martingale $M_t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}e^{-\frac{B_t^2}{2(1-t)}}$ to zero, as $t \to 1^-$
I am self-learning applied stochastic calculus from the text: A first course in Stochastic Calculus, by L.P. Arguin. Exercise problem 5.18 in my text, asks to prove the almost sure convergence of a certain process $(M_t,t\in[0,1])$. I would like for someone to give me a clue(hint) to solve part (d) of this exercise, without giving away the entire solution.

[Arguin 5.18] (A strange martingale) Let $(B_t,t\geq 0)$ be a standard Brownian motion. Consider the process:
$$
M_t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}\exp\left(\frac{-B_t^2}{2(1-t)}\right), \quad \text{ for }0 \leq t < 1
$$
(a) Show that $M_t$ can be represented by:
$$
M_t = 1 + \int_0^t \frac{-B_s M_s}{1-s}dB_s, \quad \text{ for } 0 \leq t \leq 1
$$
(b) Deduce from the previous question that $(M_s,s \leq t)$ is a martingale for $t < 1$ and for the Brownian filtration.
(c) Show that $\mathbb{E}[M_t] = 1$ for all $t < 1$.
(d) Prove that $\lim_{t \to 1^-} M_t = 0$ almost surely.

Solution(My Attempt).
Let $f(t,x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(1-t)}}$. We have:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} &= \frac{\sqrt{1-t}\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(1-t)}}\cdot \frac{x^2}{2(1-t)^2}\cdot (-1) - e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(1-t)}}\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-t}}\cdot(-1)}{(1-t)}\\
&=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(1-t)}}}{(1-t)}\left( -\frac{x^2}{2(1-t)^{3/2}}+\frac{1-t}{2(1-t)^{3/2}}\right)\\
&= \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(1-t)}}((1-t) - x^2)}{2(1-t)^{5/2}}
\end{align*}
$$
Also, the first and second derivatives with respect to the space variable $x$ are:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2(1-t)}\right)\left(-\frac{x}{(1-t)}\right)\\
&= -\frac{x}{(1-t)^{3/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2(1-t)}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} &= - \frac{1}{(1-t)^{3/2}}\left\{\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2(1-t)}\right) + x\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2(1-t)}\right)\left(-\frac{x}{(1-t)}\right)\right\}\\
&= - \frac{1}{(1-t)^{3/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2(1-t)}\right) \left\{1 - \frac{x^2}{(1-t)}\right\}\\
&= \frac{(x^2 - (1-t))}{(1-t)^{5/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2(1-t)}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
By Ito's formula:
$$
\begin{align*}
df(t,B_t) &= (f_t + \frac{1}{2}f_{xx})dt + f_x dB_t\\
dM_t &= -\frac{B_t}{(1-t)} \frac{e^{-\frac{B_t^2}{2(1-t)}}}{\sqrt{1-t}}\\
&= -\frac{B_t M_t}{(1-t)}
\end{align*}
$$
where in the second step, we used the fact that $f_t + \frac{1}{2}f_{xx} = 0$, so the $dt$ term is zero.
In the integral form:
$$
\begin{align*}
M_t - M_0 &= \int \frac{- B_s M_s}{1 - s}dB_s\\
M_t &= 1 + \int \frac{- B_s M_s}{1 - s}dB_s
\end{align*}
$$
(b) The Ito integral $\int_0^t \frac{-B_s M_s}{1-s}dB_s$ is a continuous martingale with respect to the brownian filtration. Hence $(M_t,t \geq 0)$ is a martingale.
(c) The expectation of an Ito integral is zero. Hence, $\mathbb{E}[M_t] = 1$ for all $t < 1$.
(d) Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. I might start with defining the events:
$$
A_n(\epsilon) := \{|M_{1 - \frac{1}{n}}| > \epsilon\}\\
B_n(\epsilon) := \bigcup_{m \geq n} A_m
$$
And I know, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(B_n) = 0$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for a.s. convergence. But, I don't have estimates or bounds on these probabilities.
Any inputs would be great!

We can apply the martingale convergence theorem (page 86 of your book) because we know from the previous part that $\mathbb{E}\left[M_t\right]=1 \text { for all } t<1$. Therefore, there exists a random variable $M_\infty$ such that $M_t \rightarrow M_{\infty} \text { a.s. }$. It remains to show that $M_\infty=0$. Since the supremum of Brownian motion is finite almost surely, $$M_\infty =\lim_{t\to 1^-}M_t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}} \exp \left(\frac{-B_t^2}{2(1-t)}\right)=0 \quad \text{a.s.}$$

$\mathbb{E}[\exp(-B_t^2/(1-t))] = \exp(\frac{-t}{1-t} + \frac{2t^2}{2(1-t)^2})$. I don't quite get, how you get that inequality in line 1, because $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is monotonic decreasing.

@Quasar ah yeah I applied Jensen's inequality incorrectly its convex not concave. Let me think how to salvage this

Hang on, $g(x) = e^{-x}$ is convex, since $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(e^{-x}) > 0$. And Jensen's inequality says, if $g$ is convex, $g(\mathbb{E}X) \leq \mathbb{E}[g(X)]$.

@Quasar Yeah so it goes the wrong direction for our purposes here.

@Quasar I wonder if we have to use the martingale convergence theorem. The previous part should show us that it converges almost surely to something, and we just need to show that something is 0

@Quasar Do you agree now?
